# python piping issue with while loop

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, multiprocessing, piping

I'm running a while loop that acquires frames and calculates matrices based on the image. I need to provide these matrices as inputs to another script that is controlling another data acquisition code. I have been looking at piping and multiprocessing to solve this issue but am having trouble figuring out the general formula for constantly spitting constantly updating data as an input to another script.

python noob here! over-explaining welcomed!

Niall

Comment: I agree, the question is not that clear.

Comment: I am just looking for a script that can attribute a value to memory that can be utilized by another script that is running at the same time

Comment: Do you have any example code? Or maybe an example written by someone else that does what you want?